# SQL Server: use IF statement in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

My database contains the above data. It has only code data.

Database does not have code state about string "New Member", "Leave Member", "Current Member".

So I want to query like the above right data.

In Excel, I can do this using `IF` statement. Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: where is your code? you need an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Member,
       CASE WHEN Code = 1 THEN 'New Member'
            WHEN Code = 2 THEN 'Current Member'
            WHEN Code = 3 THEN 'Leave Member'
       END AS State
FROM yourTable
```

Or you could also use an inline CTE which maps codes to states, and join this to your original table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Code, 'New Member' AS State
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Current Member'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Leave Member'
)

SELECT t1.Member,
       t2.State
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Code = t2.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case clause:

```
select Member
      ,Case code 
            when 1 then 'New Member'
            when 2 then 'Current Member'
            when 3 then 'Leave Member'
            else 'Unkown'
       end
from table1
```